# openssl_decrypt images not showing

Tags: php, openssl

I have a form where upon inserting them onto the database. I encrypt the images using open ssl and then store them in the database.

I also decrypt them and display them. The images are not showing after being pulled out of the database and then decrypted.

i can't seem to find out why the images are not showing. From what I can see they are being inserted in the database correctly

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");


  $cipher = "aes-128-cbc";
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

        $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128);


 if($_POST["action"] == "fetch")
 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images where r_id = '".$_POST["r_id"]."' ORDER BY id DESC";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  $output = '
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
    <tr>
     <th width="10%">ID</th>
     <th width="70%">Image</th>
     <th width="10%">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

      $newciphertext = $row["name"];
$newiv = $row["iv"];


 $img = openssl_decrypt($newciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $newiv);

   $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
     <td>
      <a target="_blank" href="#" onClick="enlarge(this)""><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'" class="img-thumbnail"/></a>
     </td>
     <td><button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger bt-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  echo $output;
 }

 if($_POST["action"] == "insert")
 {

  $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($file, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);

  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name, r_id, iv) VALUES ('\"" . addslashes($ciphertext) ."\"', '".$_POST["r_id"]."', '$iv')";
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Image Inserted into Database';
  }
 }
 if($_POST["action"] == "delete")
 {
  $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_images WHERE id = '".$_POST["image_id"]."'";
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Image Deleted from Database';
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you access this page a new `$iv` is calculated which is fine for the encryption part but you need the same `$iv` to decrypt the image. Therefore when you try to decrypt the image you have the wrong `$iv` and the decryption fails. You should save the `$iv` in your database either in a new field or concatenated with the encrypted image.

Comment: I amended the code now, but same thing is happening

Comment: You are also generating a new `$key` each time. Your key should be the same when you encrypt and when you decrypt. Also it must be secret so you can't store that in the database.